# How do objects get sent over a network transfer without invalidating header information

Tags: c#, c++, networking, object

Does a an object have any header data that is relative to its current machine and process, and if so, how does this object transfer over a network connection without invalidating this kind of data? I know I can't directly copy the binary data of an object across a network connection to another pc/process, and the other process on the other machine just interpret (cast) the binary data as an object.

Are there any ways to calculate how much data cut out of a binary block of data (parsed into an object) would justify using a serialized object over just passing the binary data.

Comment: you mean an object converted to a byte and then encoded for transport?

Comment: Using what method for the data transfer? And when you say "header", are you referring to the packet or to some header that exists in its serialized state? Needs more information here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A .net object can be transmitted across process boundaries in only 2 ways: Serialization and MarshalByRef.

### Serialization

This simply takes the values of (most) fields on the object and stores them in a [SerializationInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationinfo.aspx) instance.  Then, your formatter of choice converts that into bytes on a Stream.  This has no "header information" like you mention... it usually has the Type name and Assembly FullName in which the Type is defined.

### MarshalByRefObject

This is a [.NET remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) base class which means that method calls from other appdomains may be marshaled across AppDomain boundaries to this one, making it seem to users of your object that they have a reference to your object.  In this case the foreign AppDomain merely holds a proxy to your object.  This proxy holds the relevant information.

Comment: These are 2 common ways that come out of the box, but surely not the 'only' ways.  You can write your own serialization process that makes no use of SerializationInfo or Stream for example.

Comment: How much extra space does this serialization take up. I can't find that info (or does it just convert into a binary blob).

Comment: This depends entirely on the formatter you choose.  For example, the BinaryFormatter usually takes the fewest bytes.  You cannot simply copy some memory range, push it onto the wire, and expect to deserialize it on the other side appropriately, unless it's a byte array, or string, etc..  What if the receiving system is a x64 machine and has different offset?  Serialization is about your only option, though @James is correct, you can roll your own if you prefer.  Xbox-live did this with great success.  Fun article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163960.aspx

Comment: Ok, that's the answer I need.

Answer (score 2):

A general C# object is attached to its machine and process by virtue of being managed by the .net framework (so under the control of the garbage collector and so on).

But when you serialise and de serialise your object you wouldn't make any reference to such information.

It's up to you how you serialize and reconstruct objects at the other end.  It's language agnostic.

Comment: How much extra data does serialization consume. The important thing here is for me to minimize data size (network traffic).

Comment: Again that's up to you, you're controlling the serialization.  Or are you talking about some specific serialization framework?  No serialization framework I would imagine would make any reference to the kind of low level .net  framework state you're asking about however.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when transfering C# (or .NET object) all that gets transferred is the (user)state not internal .NET state. There might be internal object state of which we as ordinary programmers don't know but that is up to the developers of the .NET Runtime.

So when an object is transferred/serialized this kind of information (pointers etc.) are ignored or transformed into runtime independed identified or numbers.